# Performing Calculation on dynamic sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

Why does the following error out? It seems the SQL server doesn't recognize - operator on dynamic sql

```
DECLARE @value INT;
SELECT @value = 10;
EXEC ('SELECT ' + @value -1 );
```

Comment: Your trying to concatenate a number to a string... try this... `EXEC ('SELECT ' + @value + '-1' );`

Comment: I don't think op wants to concatenate the `-1`, I think s/he wants to decrease `@value` in 1

Comment: So, op should use: `EXEC('SELECT ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),@value-1))`

Comment: @Lamak, I get `Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'CONVERT'.` when I run your command.

Comment: @WEI_DBA ah, yeah, the real code should be something like `DECLARE @value INT, @sql nvarchar(100);
SELECT @value = 10;
SELECT @sql = N'SELECT ' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR(10),@value-1)
EXEC (@sql);`

Comment: @Lamak, I was thinking the same to put all of the select statement into a variable and then execute as you stated. +1

Comment: When you ask a question about why you are getting an error, Always Include The Error Message.

Answer (score 2):

Nope.  You should set up the statement before running it.  I would recommend:

```
DECLARE @value INT;
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX);
SET @SQL = 'SELECT @value - 1';

SELECT @value = 10;

EXEC sp_executesql @sql, N'@value int', @value = @value ;
```

This uses parameters and so is a much more sensible way to run the query.

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
DECLARE @value INT;
SELECT @value = 10;
EXEC ('SELECT ' + @value +' -1 ');
```